# Laravel email notification on some actions

Tags: laravel-5.1, vue.js

Can anyone advice me how can I add email notifications on some actions in

As I am using localhost how can i test.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: even if you are on localhost you I suggest you to create free account in mandrill/mailgun to test, or download some free fake smtp servers I do not suggest u to use your local stmp server or hotmail/gmail servers, your emails test will end up in spam and will almost never come through. Regarding email notification I suggest u to start looking at this link to start with and see if that give some useful information http://www.amitavroy.com/justread/content/articles/events-laravel-5-and-customize-model-save and  http://laravelcoding.com/blog/laravel-5-beauty-sending-mail-and-using-queues

Comment: You could use the http://mailcatcher.me/ to test the emails.